# How can I list contents of folders with Cyrillic font?

Tags: command-line, directory, cyrillic

I want to list the contents of my directories and sub-directories in a file, but the contents of the sub-directories have Russian titles. How can I do that? If I list the contents in the command prompt window the list shows correctly. This works.

```
> dir /s
```

But if I try to save the list in a document the cyrillic renders as question marks. This doesn't work.

```
> dir /s > myFiles.txt
```

Comment: See if this helps? https://superuser.com/questions/1302096/files-with-non-ascii-characters-in-file-name-in-a-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I recall correctly, under windows, you have to do two things to gain full unicode (and thus cyrillic) font support:

1. Change the console code page to UTF-8 by `chcp 65001`, see [Manpage of chcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp).
2. Ensure that your command line uses a font that supports UTF-8, for instance `Lucida Console`, there is a [lengthy description how to do that](https://www.wikihow.com/Customize-the-Font-in-Windows-Command-Prompt)

#### Related question(s)

- https://superuser.com/questions/625866/cmd-how-to-use-non-english-characters

Comment: The problem is not with using Cyrillic letters in my command line. I can navigate to folders with Cyrillic names, and make new files with Cyrillic names. So these all work fine:
> cd юлия
> echo тестюлия > тестюлия.txt

But the content of the text file is not "тестюлия", but a series of question marks.

Comment: I tried using chcp 65001, and also chcp 855 and 866, but it didn't make any difference in the output. The contents of the folder are still listed incorrectly.

Comment: Do you have an editor like `notepad++` where you can actively change the encoding and try different ones? Auto-detect might went wrong in your editor, there are other cyrillic encodings other than UTF-8.

Comment: If I do type myFiles.txt then all the files are listed in the command prompt window and the character encoding is incorrect.

Comment: I have tried to change the encoding in notepad++ and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: But, you mentioned PowerShell, and that gave me an idea. I decided to try with GitBash instead of Windows Command Prompt, and it worked!
Saving the directories and sub-directories as a txt file resulted in proper character encoding, but one long string of data. Saving in a doc file worked well.Used 
$ ls -R >myFiles.doc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197062/discussion-between-hgamble-and-b-rian).

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to download a Unix shell command line interface. I used Git Bash.

```
ls -R > myFiles.doc
```

All my files are listed correctly in the Cyrillic font.